# Nuxt 3 HMR with Docker

Tags: docker, vite, nuxtjs3, webpack-hmr

Is HMR throw WSL on Docker working only with `server.watch: { usePolling: true }` option enabled. It's really make my CPU to be crazy.
Anyone try to switch to the Webpack intead of Vite to solve this issue?

P.S. I don't use any 'servers' like nginx, just scaffold nuxt 3 app. And i tried to expose the porst like

```
ports:
  - 3000:3000
  - 24678:24678 # hmr fix
```

But in dev. console I get error: `[GET] http://localhost:24678/_nuxt/ not found`

UPD. As @DavidMaze said in the comments, the simplest solution is just use my host machine for nuxt and docker for other tools.

Comment: Does this setup work with plain Node, without Docker?  What benefits are you getting from using Docker here?

Comment: @DavidMaze Yes, it works well without Docker, but I need it to build one dev. environment along my team. Plus I need another tools like pgsql, redis, etc. for this and future projects.

Comment: You can use Docker for things like databases, in combination with Node without Docker for actual development.  Actually installing Node is usually a one-line invocation of your host package manager, it is probably strictly easier than anything involving Docker.

Comment: You rigth. This is the simplest solution for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to follow this up with a solution that worked for me, which was to expose port `24678` in the Dockerfile and setting the ports in `compose.yaml`.

Dockerfile

```
...
EXPOSE 3000
EXPOSE 24678
```

compose.yaml

```
...
ports:
  - 3000:3000
  - 24678:24678
```